# Checkbox not working in asp.net and HTML mixed page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I'm grappling with an issue where the site is asp.net/C# but controls on the .aspx pages are HTML and I'm not sure how well it would go over if I would change everything into asp.net controls. Also the change is minor. I was tasked to add a check box, as in `<input type="checkbox" name="disableFeatureManager" runat="server" id="disableFeatureManager" />Disable Feature Manager` and in the .cs page I want to check if the box is checked and make decisions based on that, but the control's checked property is always `false`. The submit button is also a HTML control: `<input type="submit" value="Start" name="submitButton" />`

In the `Page_Load` ckecking if check like this returns false.

```
if (disableFeatureManager != null && disableFeatureManager.Checked)
    nextURL.Append(FeatureManagerChoices.CreateQueryStringFromFormData(Request.Form));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned before, I was trown into the deep end of MVC. Co-worker offered a simple answer(as least in this case):

```
bool isChecked = false;
if(Request["disableFeatureManager"] != null)
    isChecked = (Request["disableFeatureManager"].ToLower() == "on");

if (!isChecked)
    nextURL.Append(FeatureManagerChoices.CreateQueryStringFromFormData(Request.Form));
```

I think this can be further simplified in to one `IF` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep your checkbox as an Html server control by doing the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="disableFeatureManager" runat="server" id="disableFeatureManager" />
```

Then you could change your button to a web control as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="submitStart" runat="server" OnClick="btn1_Click" Text="Start" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

The only difference with the above rendered HTML will be the name that is output but you will have an Id that is `submitStart` due to the `ClientIdMode` being static, if you need a friendly consistent Id for javascript manipulation.

To wire in the event add this code which will read the value from the checkbox:

```
    protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var isChecked = disableFeatureManager.Checked;
    }
```

[image: Checked image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. In the Page_Load there is StringBuilder object that is being appended based on different conditions, one of which is this FeatureManager call, so I need to have the value from the check box in the Page_Load. Also, I just remembered, this is a MVC 2 app and I've not worked with MVC before.

Comment: @Risho Oh right. It wasn't tagged up as an MVC question. Can you provide the code for the View, and Action(s) that are involved with the Page_Load?

Comment: My bad, as I said, my first MVC app and was tossed into the deep end. Completely forgot. This is a huge solution, and I'll do my best to post the code you requested.